# Javers SpringBoot integration QueryBuilder byInstanceId returns empty result

Tags: java, spring-boot, javers

I'm using springboot integration from this example:

https://github.com/l7777777b/organization-structure

It's my forked example from:

https://github.com/javers/organization-structure

using mysql and recent version of Javers 5.6.3, gradle 5.4.1 and springboot 2.1.6.RELEASE.

First im not sure if its an expected behaviour, but the changes and snapshot return empty result when using `QueryBuilder.byInstanceId` , but when using `QueryBuilder.byClass` it shows correctly.

`QueryBuilder.byInstanceId` can show results for newly inserted data, for existing data (data already on database prior the service started) it seems not getting fetched.

To reproduce it:

1. run the service like usual `./gradlew organization-structure-sql:bootRun`
2. create new person

   ```
    POST http://localhost:8080/view/person
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Yang",
        "lastName": "Huajie",
        "sex": "MALE",
        "salary": 22,
        "position": "DEVELOPER"
    }
   ```
3. update it, change any property
4. get snapshots using this code:

   ```
    QueryBuilder jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.byInstanceId("1", Person.class);
    List<CdoSnapshot> changes = javers.findSnapshots(jqlQuery.build());
    JsonConverter jsonConverter = javers.getJsonConverter();
    System.out.println(jsonConverter.toJson(changes));
   ```
5. it should be showing some data, then restart the service. or force stop it and run number 1.
6. get the same snapshots again by running number 4, and it should be showing empty result. unless i insert new data, the newly inserted data will be returned.

But if i change `QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(personId, Person.class);` into `QueryBuilder.byClass(Person.class);` i can get all result from database correctly, but i only need to search specific id that's why i need to use `byInstanceId`.

Comment: its look like id is Integer and you are passing a String value to the byInstanceId("1"), could you please try to change it to int and check.

Comment: Hey thanks, it does work. i really didn't think that one going to matter since the database store the local id as string and the example also have the login as string, and also the snapshots can show up if i insert new data even when i use string id.

Comment: hey, welcome your issue resolved?

Comment: yes it does resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its look like id is Integer and you are passing a String value to the
 `byInstanceId("1")`, could you please try to change it to int and check ex. `byInstanceId(1)`